# How to apply interval discounts to original shopping cart price

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

I have the following scenario

Buy 10 - 24 items get 10% discount
Buy 25 - 49 items get 15% discount
Buy 50 items or more get 20% discount

How to I get Magento to always take the discount from the original subtotal price. Currently Magento works okay for the first 10% discount but once it goes into the 2nd bracket it applies the extra 5% discount to the altered 10% price and not the original subtotal price so the customer does not get the full 15% off if buying 25 - 49 items.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set up 3 Shopping Cart Price Rules.

---

`The 3 rules:`

[image: The 3 rules:]

`Rule 1:`

[image]

[image]

`Rule 2:`

[image]

[image]

`Rule 3:`

[image]

[image]