# How to Apply more then 4 price cart rules

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart

I have the following scenario

Buy 2 items get 10% discount Buy 3 items get 12% discount Buy 4 items get 30% discount buy 5 items get 40% discount buy 6 or more get 50% discount

How to I get Magento to always take the discount from the original subtotal price. Currently Magento works okay for the first 10% discount but once it goes into the 2nd bracket it not applies the discount on subtotal i follow this rule

[How to apply interval discounts to original shopping cart price](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54428/how-to-apply-interval-discounts-to-original-shopping-cart-price)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for stackexchange i solved it thank you [image]